# Application insights add series for custom property

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a query for application insights that is very close to what I want but I think I must be misunderstanding something that I need the penny to drop for.

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(1d) and name contains("x.Ticks.")
| extend platform = tostring(customDimensions.Platform)
| summarize avg(todouble(customMeasurements.Average)) by name, platform, bin(timestamp, 1m)
| render linechart
```

This query will create a series per event `name`, with values averaged over 1m for the `Average` metric, plotted against time. I think.

What I want is there to be a cross product of series per event `name` and per `Platform` property. So a series for Event A and Platform A, Event B and Platform A, Event A and Platform B, Event B and Platform B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by doing the following:

```
| summarize avg(todouble(customMeasurements.Average)) by strcat(name, " ", platform), bin(timestamp, 1m)
```

Comment: This is so succinct and simple, I was trying too hard to make it complicated when it turns out there was no need! Thanks.